# Deleting a range of items in a list versus printing a range of items in a list

Tags: python, list, printing, append

Observe the code below:

```
1   names = ['Louisa', 'Mean Girl Star Wars Fan', 'Olive']
2   names.append('Stephen')
3   names.append('Lucia')
4   names.append('Gianna')
5   names.append('Sal')
6   names.append('Andrew')
7   names.append('Francesca...we think')
8   names.append('Peter or John')
9   del names[0:3]
10  print(names[0:6])
```

Why is it that I must specify a range of [0:3] to delete the first 3 entries in list names yet when I wish to print 6 names in the list  I have to specify print(names[0:6])?

Comment: probably b/c you're using python 3.+ which restricts `print` to be called solely as `print(<input>)`.  See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[del](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) is a [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), in `python 3` print is a `function` so you have to call it.